# Protractor gives error if i do not move mouse on the webpage

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, protractor

If i move the mouse on the web page, then protractor tests are successful. It seems that the application is looking for mouse event, and because of this the protractor is giving me the error "Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 40 seconds". No matter what the allScriptsTimeout i give in configuration file, same error it shows.

I had no other option except to use ignoresynchronization. But i do not want to use ignoresynchronization option as i had to give browser.wait for all the elements which is tedious. So is there any workaround to handle the mouse events in protractor. The application under test uses angular.

Comment: Could you please show your config, specify what Protractor and what browser are you using? Is the behavior consistent in different browsers? Thanks.

Comment: Yes the behaviour is same with both chrome and firefox. 
Below is my config file

    framework: 'jasmine2',
    directConnect: true,
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    capabilities: {
     'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    specs: ['testcases_p_m_spec.js'],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000
    },
    untrackOutstandingTimeouts: true,
    allScriptsTimeout: 40000,
    }